# É uma boa prática utilizar <summary> para documentação?

Tags: c#, documentação, summary

Essa é a melhor forma de documentar código no C#?

```
/// <summary>
/// Descrição
/// </summary>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### O summary é usado pelo Visual Studio

Essa é a forma **padrão** de criar documentação para o código feito em C#. **É daí que o Visual Studio tira as explicações sobre o que o método faz** para mostrar quando você aponta o mouse no método ou propriedade.

Quando você está fazendo uma chamada de uma função por exemplo, cada parâmetro pode ter uma explicação diferente do que ele faz. Isso é mostrado pelo Visual Studio, durante a codificação o que ajuda muito.

### O summary pode ser usado para gerar documentação

Existem ferramentas capazes de gerar a documentação para você quando você usa esse tipo de documentação. **O próprio Visual Studio, quando você compilar um código também gera um XML com essa documentação**, a qual você pode enviar juntamente com suas bibliotecas para prover documentação dentro do Visual Studio... assim como acontece quando você aponta o mouse sobre o método.

**[Leia mais sobre documentação XML, ou Xml-Doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/b2s063f7.aspx)**

Answer (score 13):

Sim.

Não apenas o `<summary>`, mas todos os itens de documentação. Essas informações são mapeadas pelo IntelliSense do Visual Studio e aparecem no *Code Completion* (completar-código).

Não apenas isso, se você deseja gerar uma documentação para os objetos e métodos escritos, as ferramentas de geração utilizam estas informações para construir a documentação automaticamente.

O corpo mínimo da documentação possui o seguinte:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Método selecionar padrão. Recebe uma lista de operadores para selecionar do banco e devolver uma lista
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="operadores"></param>
    /// <param name="tipoResolucao"></param>
    /// <returns>Lista de operadores tipada.</returns>
    /// <remarks>Deve ser implementado em cada classe derivada.</remarks>
```

- **summary**: Um resumo do que o método faz;
- **param** (podem ser colocados vários): Os parâmetros utilizados pelo método, se houver;
- **returns**: Explicação geral sobre o retorno do método, se houver;
- **remarks**: Observações sobre o método, que sejam útil para outros programadores.

Há várias outras tags para documentação. Para vê-las, basta acrescentar três barras e abrir a tag (<) que aparecerão mais opções no **Code Completion**.

Comment: Essa estrutura é a mesma coisa se eu tivesse usando um comentário no codigo?

Comment: @CristianSouza Sim.